# Как лучше инициализировать DOM-элементы при подключении JavaScript-файла в конец документа?

Tags: javascript, html

Как известно, оптимальным с точки зрения производительности методом подключения JavaScript-файлов является их подключение в конец документа (перед закрывающим тэгом `<body>`). Такой подход лишает нас возможности использовать функции, объявленные в данных файлах до тех пор, пока документ не будет полностью загружен например так:

```
<button id="btn1">Push me</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
    initBtn1();
    // а объявлена функция во внешнем файле, подключённом в конце документа,
    // потому не сработает
</script>
```

В этом вопросе я рассматриваю инициализацию DOM-элементов на примере добавления обработчиков нажатия на кнопки. Сперва уточню, что я подразумеваю под *инициализацией* (быть может, я понимаю данный термин ошибочно).

Если говорить о динамическом создании веб-страницы, то этот процесс можно разделить на 2 этапа:

1. **Генерация HTML-кода**: формирование конечного HTML-кода объединением шаблона и данных; может происходить и на стороне сервера (с помощью языка PHP и шаблонизатора), и уже на стороне клиента с помощью JavaScript.
2. **Инициализация HTML-кода (в том числа и DOM-элементов)**: внедрение логики в HTML-код; в основном я имею ввиду добавление обработчиков действий пользователя и других событий, а также получение свойств (например, ширины конкретного блока `<div>`).

Второй этап должен производиться только после того, как в браузере отображается хотя бы HTML-код тех DOM-элементов, которые мы инициализируем.

### Задача

Есть сайт с несколькими страницами (т. е. НЕ single-page JS application), и на каждой странице есть кнопки, на которые нужно повесить обработчики. Естественно, что вешать обработчики нужно только на те кнопки, которые уже отображаются на данной странице.

Раньше я это делал так:

- Для каждой страницы писал функции типа `initButtonsOnPage1()`, `initButtonsOnPage2()` и т. д.
- Подключал JS-файлы в `<head>`, что является распространённой, но ущербной для производительности практикой.
- В конце `<body>` конкретной страницы вызывал нужную функцию, как в примере выше.

Вопрос: как решить поставленную задачу, если JavaScript-файлы (а вернее один минифицированный JS-файл, полученный из нескольких) теперь будет подключен в конец `<body>`, при этом тэг `<script>` должен быть только один?

На данный момент я придумал только такой способ решения задачи:

```
// Узнаём текущий URL
var currentURL = window.location.href;
// Отсекаем протокол и домен
var currentURLpath = currentURL.replace('http://www.example.com/', '');

/*
В зависимости от страницы запускаем нужную функцию инициализации, 
каждая из которых выполняется в момент onload, когда нужная страница загружена
*/
switch(currentURLpath){
    case 'page1': { initPage1Elements(); break;}
    case 'page2': { initPage2Elements(); break;}
    case 'page3': { initPage3Elements(); break;}
    // ...
    default: { break; }
}
```

Какие имеются более хорошие альтернативы данному способу? (Решения с помощью готовых движков типа `ReactJS` и `Angular` рассматривать не будем).

Comment: Можно попробовать искать кнопку после загрузки дома и в случае ее нахождения вешать обработчик, а если не нашел, то ничего не делать. Прочитайте про загрузку дома https://learn.javascript.ru/onload-ondomcontentloaded с помощью этих событий можно не мучатся с подключением в хеад и последующим вызовом, а делать все в одном файле.

Comment: Что-то слишком сложно у Вас как то... А если страниц будет сотня? Вы будете писать сотню функций для каждой страницы? Намного лучше делать в стиле ООП, причем каждый интерактивный элемент - это компонент, у него есть свой метод инициализации, а именно нашел в DOM нужный элемент, про инициализировался, т.е. выполнилась функция конструктор, нету этого элемента на странице `return`

Comment: @pepel_xD, _Вы будете писать сотню функций для каждой страницы?_ вместо сотни функций ты предлагаешь писать сотню компонентов?

Comment: @pepel_xD, такие сайты, в которых сотня **ключевых** страниц, надо ещё поискать. Ну а для однотипных страниц одна и та же функция сойдёт.

Comment: @Grundy, зачем.... допустим та же кнопка... это компонент..  у него есть свой коструктор, допустим принимает DOM элемент и функцию обработчик клика

Comment: @pepel_xD, и если обработчики разные, то выходит те же самые сто компонентов